# How to install ubuntu 16.04 on a HP Stream 11

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I would like to keep the preinstalled Windows 10 for the rare case I need it (I know that I will need Windows for Taxman). The Stream 11 I have is a 4GB RAM, 32GB eMMC, Celeron N3060 1.6gHz, 64 bit. I received it today, so it is brand new.
Do I have enough space on it to run both OSs? 
Is the processor good enough for this? 
Is there a good tutorial to do this? 
Windows 10 is already taking 14GB, 13.7GB are still available. Is there enough storage on it? I will add an SD card for my files so don't need the internal storage for that.

Comment: I very much doubt there is enough space.

Comment: Also see [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](/q/206407/175814) which tells us that the minimal space requirement for Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 is 10 GB.

Comment: Is there a way to completely remove Windows 10 and keep it for further use (e.g. reselling the laptop with factory settings)? In this case I would have plenty of room to install Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I would like to know where the exact duplicate is. In any case I just finished installing Ubuntu 16.04 on this computer after removing Windows 10. I had tried Lubuntu but was not satisfied. Ubuntu installed without any trouble.